# Issue with Group.ReadWrite.All permission scope

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am playing off with Microsoft Graph Group.ReadWrite.All delegated permission scope. The Azure AD App is configured with this permission.

Since it is a delegated permission, the privileges granted to the app will be the least privileged combination (the intersection) of the privileges granted by the scope and those possessed by the signed-in user.

After admin consent to the app, I have used normal user credential and retrieved the token. With this token, I can update the members of a private Office 365 Group, even though the user is not an admin in that private group.

This behavior seems incorrect. Please clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So when you use delegated permissions, the app has the same permissions as the signed-in user, further limited by the permissions granted to the app.  In this case, you are correct about the intersection of permissions - the app is allowed to update the private group's membership, BUT only if the signed-in user has the ability to also update the private group's membership.  In this case, if the user is not an admin of the group, then the app should not be able to update the group membership through the API (in the context of this signed in user).

UPDATE:
I was able to repro this.  Currently (through the API) members of a private can add other members to the group.  I suspect your user in your test is a member of the group. (Non-members could not add members to the private group.) We are presently working on a fix for this issue.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks. Please post us once it is fixed.

Comment: Hi @Dan, whether this issue is fixed?